# YouTube API CSS & Control with more than one player

Tags: javascript, css, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

i trying to create a page that contains 2 or more YouTube players that are control by links in JavaScript, actually i read the YouTube API documentation a few times and i still cannot understand how can i embed 2 or more different players and still control them with the links ytplayer thing... the other problem is that i cant make design changes to those players using DIV and CSS, when I'm doing it nothing changes, can any one please help me, I'm pretty new with this stuff...
here's the basic code, what i should do ?
here's a link for the code:

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bZQa1euR

Comment: Could you create a http://jsfiddle.net with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

I've always found this to be a useful tactic

```
function stop(videoId) {
    ytplayer = document.getElementById(videoId);
    ytplayer.stopVideo();
};
```

Then you just use

```
<a href="" onclick="stop('videoid')">Stop</a>
```